# Sqlite Join (or some variant thereof)

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Given a resultset like this:

```
Col1    Col2
============
BAML    491
BARC    362
BDPT    1
BNP     9
```

(select Col1, count(some_col) as Col2 from Table where another_col='SomeCondition" group by Col1)

and another like this:

```
Col3    Col2
============
BAML    494
BARC    366
BDPT    1
BNP     10
CALY    3
```

(select Col3, count(some_col) as Col2 from Table where another_col='SomeOTHERCondition" group by Col3)

How do I "merge" these two queries to form:

```
BAML    491       494
BARC    362       366
BDPT    1         1
BNP     9         10
CALY              3
```

Please note that the first two queries operate on the *same* table. I can see some variant of Join helping here (haven't worked with sql all that much). I just can't figure out how to put those two queries into a single query to get the merged reusltset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select b.col1, b.col2, a.col2
from (
    select Col3, count(some_col) as Col2
    from Table
    where another_col = 'SomeOTHERCondition'
    group by Col3
) as a
left outer join (
    select Col1, count(some_col) as Col2
    from Table
    where another_col = 'SomeCondition'
    group by Col1
) as b
on a.col3 = b.col1
```

I'm not sure if SQLite supports that though.

---

Based on the comments the above does work but you really want a FULL OUTER JOIN and SQLite doesn't like that. You could try faking it with two LEFT OUTER JOINs and a UNION though:

```
select b.col1, b.col2, a.col2
from ... as a left outer join ... as b ...
UNION
select b.col1, b.col2, a.col2
from ... as b left outer join ... as a ...
```

Comment: that monster works like a charm! :-) only problem is it misses entries on the right table that don't satisfy the join criteria with the left table. Do I actually need a full outer join? because I want non-matching rows to be included too.

Comment: @Dilip: Yes, you might need a full outer join, you should be able to replace "left" with "full".

Comment: Luckily for me Sqlite supports neither Right nor Full outer joins! Grr.. (btw, when I start off my comments with "@mu:" to address you, that part gets eaten up and only my comments show. why?)

Comment: @Dilip: You could use a UNION of two LEFT JOINs to fake the FULL OUTER JOIN. And the `@mu` probably gets eaten because I get notified of all comments on my answers.